# How to use OR operator in find method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, conditional-operator

how could I use something like this:

```
@comments = @company.comments.where(:approved => true).or(:ip => request.remote_ip).all
```

Should I have to install any specific gem for doing this?

I using rails 3.0.4 and mysql2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "Conditions" section [in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), where it explains using multiple parameters in the conditions. Your query would be written:

```
@comments = @company.comments.where('approved = ? OR ip = ?', true, request.remote_ip).all
```